# Traffic light, no more shapes?

Tags: physical

I remember when I was a kid. Each traffic lights had different shapes. Red = Square, Yellow = Triangle, Green = Circle. Now all the traffic lights that I see are round.

Is there a reason why they don't need to have different shape any more?
Isn't it harder for people that have trouble with colors?

[image: Before]
(Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic-light_signalling_and_operation#mediaviewer/File:Colourblind_traffic_signal.JPG)

[image: Now]
<sub>(source: [dec-ced.gc.ca](https://www.dec-ced.gc.ca/docs/leddartech2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Fun fact: green and red are easily confused when you have various types of colour blindness, so the green also contains blue light, making it easier to discern!

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen traffic lights with those shapes (I'm in California). When and where did these exist?

Comment: @Keith Quebec/Canada

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Its more expensive to manufacture and maintain different shaped lights.
2. Round hoods on each light provide better shielding against sunlight and better protection against rain (quicker dissipation) and wind by being more aerodynamic (less resistance).
3. Parts are more interchangeable. Examples: One hood fits on all the lights. The clear tempered glass cover on the red light also fits on the other lights. Clear glass is less expensive than colored glass.
4. Even color-blind people know where the red, yellow and green lights are located.
5. (not relevant to this question) Each light is now made up of a matrix of small LED's. If one LED fails, the rest keep on working. As we know, LED's are brighter, more energy-efficient and last much longer than regular bulbs.

Comment: #5 was very interesting to know

Comment: Interesting points. Do you have any links to the various sources where you've found this information?

Comment: No links, these are my own common sense opinions.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Although I did not obtain this info from any source, my common sense made these assumptions.

Comment: I think it's a false assumption that different shapes for the lights would have to mean different shapes for the hoods, although it might require rounding off the top corners of the square red light. See another answer to this question for examples with different shapes and symbols in current use.

Answer (score 11):

I think your basic assumption that they are all the same now is wrong, or at least very locally biased. Where I'm from, there are plenty of different shapes in use. Most notable are the pedestrian lights:
[image: Basic green light] [image: Basic red light]

However, there are many variations, even animating ones:
[image: Animating pedestrian light]

and ones with different count-downs:
[image: Light with countdown 1] [image: Light with countdown 2]

There are also special versions for bikes:
[image: Bike light green 1]
[image: Bike light green 2]
[image: Bike light red]

Then, of course, there are also the arrows-type lights, in use for cars:
[image: Left red sign for cars]
[image: Set of arrow-type lights for cars]

To conclude: it is hardly the case that there are only circles in use these days.

Comment: I live in Canada, here's an example: http://www.dec-ced.gc.ca/docs/leddartech2.jpg

Comment: Great examples!

Comment: In the United States, the U.S. Dept. of Transportation has uniform standards for traffic lights, and all other transportation devices, signs, etc. See (http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/pdfs/2009r1r2/mutcd09r1r2editionhl.pdf)

Comment: By The Mall, in London, there are pedestrian crossing lights and horse-rider crossing lights. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

From a great distance, like traffic lights are often viewed from, it is hard to discern shapes--especially square vs. circle.

Glare and flaring tend to reduce the light to a blur anyway (except for those have 20/20 vision and perfectly clear eyeballs viewing them through a clean windshield on a clear day). The color becomes the predominant signal--and therefore it is quantity of light that becomes important.

The above examples all cut down on the amount of light leaving the signal-- especially the "bicycle" and "pedestrian" shapes (which are appropriate for the slower-moving clientele they serve, but would blur into "dim green"/"dim red" for car drivers, especially in the rain.

As @Matt mentioned in a comment to the question, the 'green' traffic lights often have a strong blue component so that RG-colorblind people have a better chance of distinguishing them, the major argument against relying solely on color.

Position provides an additional reinforcement, and a top-down arrangement is clearer than a left-right (or is it right-left?) arrangement, which was the other notably confusing thing about shaped Canadian traffic lights.

Comment: The arrows for cars do serve a purpose. They are used here only in situations where there are different sorting lanes for cars turning in different directions, and these may be allowed to go at different times. For instance, turning right is allowed now, but turning left is not. Also note that the animation might actually better catch the eye than a solid light. I know it works like that in computer UI's where animations are really quite powerful at drawing the eye. That *may* make up for the reduction in the amount of light.

Comment: Arrows definitely serve a purpose, and tend to be engaged at shorter distances than the round balls (because you tend to slow down to take a curve). Animation may draw the eye--especially blinking--and this may not be preferable, given the confusion of signals in front of a driver. We reserve blinking for specific meanings tied to the color of the lights; an animation that is confusable with blinking better have a similar meaning...

Comment: Note that the animated lights are used for pedestrians only, which is the one you thought suffered from dimished light and, as you rightly stated, is much slower traffic. Note that animations are used for car drivers as well though: the flashing light on police cars or other services, and things like closed off lanes on roads that may be signalled using an animated arrow pointing towards the open lane(s) next to it.

Comment: @André. There's also blinking amber lights at pedestrian crossings, which basically mean that cars are free to move if the pedestrian has cleared the crossing.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the shapes started disappearing when traffic lights were being retrofitted with LEDs.  When they started doing that, they didn't simply put the LEDs inside the reflection cones behind the lenses as one might have expected, but instead put disc-shaped LED matrices on the outsides of the lenses.  At least, that's what it kind of looked like.

If you watch for them, on some signal heads you can still see square hoods where the red lights were.  Incidentally, they changed the standard of signal arrangement: where, before, the right and left arrows were on the outermost positions of the signal head, now it is always the red lights that are outermost, and the right and left arrows are usually adjacent to the green and/or yellow lights.  This results in the arrow lights sometimes having square hoods.  Some signal heads have all square hoods, as in the one pictured in the question.

Some LED traffic lights were made with the shapes, but, for some reason, even those are hard to find now.  During a recent visit to Quebec, I saw exactly two shape-coded traffic lights.  They used to be all over the place.

I liked having the shape coded lights because they were something slightly strange that you see only in (eastern) Canada, giving tourists the impression (even if only subliminally) that this isn't just an extremity of the U.S.

Sorry for the thread bump in case that's a big deal here.